How to stop scheduled run base on previous test result
I have GitHub Actions workflow that runs my sanity tests:
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  schedule:
    - cron: '*/30 5-20 * * 1-5'

What I want is to stop/disable schedule run option if steps.run_tests.outcome != 'success
When tests fails I would like only to run them on workflow_dispatch:
If workflow_dispatch run results are 'success' schedule run shall start again.
I have tried to use lock run file but it do not work:
      - name: Lock run 
        if: always() && steps.run_tests.outcome != 'success'
        run: |
          echo "failure" > last_run_status.txt  # Store failure status
            exit 0
      - name: Unlock run
        if: always() && steps.run_tests.outcome == 'success'
        run: |
          echo "success" > last_run_status.txt  # Store success status
          exit 0


In a workflow, a container/image is started which is discarded after the process is completed. You must save the file in a cache or on an external memory, which can also be an external server.

There is no persistance of data by default between 2 jobs. You need to use artifacts in order to achieve what you are trying to do: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/writing-workflows/choosing-what-your-workflow-does/storing-and-sharing-data-from-a-workflow
